# qgis and geoserver or national map download

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I am trying to get layers into qgis. Using QGis 2.18, Web, GeoServer, but get the message 'Tried to make a GET request to http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces.xml but got a 503 status code'.

How do I add layers from the U.S. National Map Download site?

At this site, I can't seen to get to the correct URL.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to get QGis to load the workspaces list from the GeoServer REST api. This will not work (though why it returns a 503 I'm not sure), the GeoServer REST api is for management of GeoServer resources not for access to maps.

You want to add the `GetCapabilities` document of your service to the matching client in QGis. So for a WMS layer you will want to use the URL `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities`. For the US national map site you will be looking for a similar URL.

Comment: With that url I get the following '&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=Getcapilities, server replied - service unavailable'. I'm using 'Layer, Add layer, Add WMS,WMTS layer'

Comment: do you actually have GeoServer installed and listening on port 8080? - what is the response if you use that url in your browser?